# stub a function in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a model stores data into db then calls another store method by passing the id just created

```
 //db.Poll.store method  

 store: function (opt, db, callback) {
            var pollData = {
                question: opt.data.question
            };

            db.Poll.create(pollData).success(function (poll) {
                opt.data.PollId = poll.id;
                models.PollOption.store(opt, db, callback);
            }).error(function(error) {
                callback(error, null);
            });
        }
```

I just want to have a unit test to make sure a valid opt.data.PollId is passed to models.PollOption.store() method and I don't want to check if models.PollOption.store() behaviour correctly or not, so I mocked/overwritten the models.PollOption.store method. my unit test is like this below

```
describe('Method store', function () {
    it('should be able to create a poll and pass poll.id to pollOption.store', function (done) {
        var opt = {
            data: {
                question: "Do you love nodejs?"
            }
        };

        var temp = db.PollOption.store;
        //mock function
        db.PollOption.store = function (opt, db, callback) {
            expect(opt.data.PollId).not.to.be.empty
            //restore to what it was before
            db.PollOption.store = temp;
            callback();
        };

        db.Poll.store(opt, db, done);
    });
});
```

Can I achieve this by using sinon.js , stub db.PollOption.store method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used another test framework, and since i dont have your full code, so here is an example of how to use sinon.spy

basically, the eq(1, opt) means expect(opt).equal.to(1)

```
var method = { store : function(a){
  return a+1
}}

tests({
   'should be able to create a poll and pass poll.id to pollOption.store': function () {
      sinon.spy(method, "store")              // create spy
      method.store({opt:1})                   // call your function
      var spyCall = method.store.getCall(0)   // sinon spy API .getCall(0)
                                              // i assume this is the [objects] 
                                              // created by the spy on calling method()
      eq(1, spyCall.args[0].opt)              // your expect()
    }
});
```

Comment: since the method db.PollOption.store is inside db.Poll.store, your spy the method won't get called

Comment: That is fine, but you would need a promise/resolve for it to spy on models.PollOption.store(opt, db, callback), its async